# How to match length of variable size backreference but not content

Tags: python, regex

Currently I'm trying to write a regular expression (using Python's re module) that will find occurrences of 'a' in a string of a given length. There are a few different patterns I'm trying to match, but the ones that are giving me trouble look like this:

```
a.a.a
a..a..a
a...a...a
```

Basically I'm trying to find matches that contain at least three occurrences of 'a', but they must be equally spaced apart. So far I've tried regexes:

```
regex1 = r'a(.|..|...)a\1a'

regex2 = r'a(.{1,3})a\1a'
```

But the problem I'm having is that the backreference repeats the matched text. So, for example, my regex will match #1 but not #2,

```
1. aoooaoooa
2. aoooabbba
```

when in actuality I don't care about the content between occurrences of 'a', simply the distance.

I know backreferences can be used to match the same unknown text multiple times, but I suppose I don't know enough to tell whether there's just a different way to use them, or whether I should be using some other method/pattern entirely. Tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python `re` module does not have this feature, [PCRE does (`\g<1>`)](https://regex101.com/r/pN5vU1/1).

Comment: I'm a bit confused about PCRE - is it for use while programming in Perl? I haven't had experience with Perl yet, but I suppose it's never too late to learn :)

Comment: No, PCRE is not only used in Perl. It is a regex engine used in PHP. Did you hear of PyPi regex module? It can also recurse subpatterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install [Python PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can use subpattern recursing features. Just wrap a repeating part with a capture group, and then use `(?n)` where *n* is the capture group ID.

```
>>> import regex
>>> a = "aoooaoooa"
>>> b = "aoooabbba"
>>> rx = r"a(.{1,3})a(?1)a"
>>> print(regex.search(rx, a).group(0))
aoooaoooa
>>> print(regex.search(rx, b).group(0))
aoooabbba
>>> print(regex.search(rx, "abacca").group(0))
abacca
```

**Explanation**:

- `a` - matches a literal `a`
- `(.{1,3})` - matches and **captures into Group 1** one to three characters other than a newline
- `a` - matches a literal `a`
- **`(?1)`** - a recursive construct telling the regex engine retreive the *pattern* rather than the value that belongs to Group 1 (i.e. `.{1,3}`)
- `a` - matches a literal `a`

**PyPi regex module does not support balanced constructs** (.NET can), so you will have to add more code to check if you matched groups of equal length. Fortunately, regex module keeps all captured submatches in the `.captures` object. So, all you need to do to exclude `abacca` from the valid matches is to use:

```
c = "abacca"
m = regex.search(rx, c)
if len(max(m.captures(1))) - len(min(m.captures(1))) == 0: # all of equal length ?
    print m.group(0)
```

Comment: If I understand the question, there's supposed to be the same *number* of characters between each pair (so `abaca` or `abcadea` should match, but `abacca` shouldn't).  Which could be tough even in PyPi.

Comment: @AlanMoore: True, I could not find a balanced construct definition in the regex module. Thus, there must be an additional step in the code to check for the captured group item length. Since captures are not lost (the stack is available for each capture group), we can make sure all of them are of equal length. I added that check to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I actually did, but since I'm a relatively new user my upvotes weren't appearing for a small time. I have enough reputation now though and my vote is showing. Thanks again!